# C/C++: How to create matlab like structure array

Tags: c++, c, matlab

I am wondering if it's possible to write a code for creating structure array in C/C++ just like Matlab.

```
For instance, in Matlab, I can di:
patient.name = 'John Doe';
patient.billing = 127.00;
patient.test = [79, 75, 73; 180, 178, 177.5; 220, 210, 205];
```

without defining struct as a separate piece of code. What I like is that I can add any field later on.

I have no idea how to write a piece of code in C/C++ which can do the same thing. Some guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't trival in C++. It's kind of against the grain of the language. What new fields do you want to add, and under what circumstances? There may be a better way.

Comment: @Garima If requirement is to add a new patient.address in structure dynamically  it is impossible in C++

Comment: @NeilKirk If it's not easy to do so in C++, then I guess that I can manage with usual C/C++ struct.

Comment: Just use a `std::unordered_map` with `std::string`-keys and `boost::variant`-values (or `boost::any`). That should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Matlab, by considering your piece of code as requirement we can do as follows in C++.

```
struct patient{
 std::string name;
 double billing;
 std::vector<float> test;
}

std::vector<patient> patients;
```

Comment: The requirement is to add new fields dynamically.

Comment: @Niel Kirk Thanks to make it clear .If requirement is to add a new patient.address in structure dynamically  it is impossible in C++

Comment: @Steephen , Niel Kirk is right, I want to create the field dynamically.